# ASP.Net MVC ViewBag is not working in View. ViewBag result is Correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I am having an issue with ViewBag not working in view. The controller returns what i think i need..

On debugging I have Current = false and then on Results View i also have false. The bit is set to false. 
It seems that all the ViewBag items return False for Current.

When i call the ViewBag in my View it does not seem to do anything. It doesn't fault out either.

Here is my section of code where i am getting current bool info from an array.

```
 if (GetOrPost == "GET")
 {
    if (actionName == "add" || actionName == "index" || actionName == "create" || actionName == "edit" || actionName == "delete" || actionName == "multiviewindex")
    {
      ViewBag.Add = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsAdd));
      ViewBag.Read = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsRead));
      ViewBag.Create = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsCreate));
      ViewBag.Edit = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsUpdate));
      ViewBag.Delete = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsDelete));
    }
  }
```

This is the usage in the view:

```
  @if (ViewBag.Edit = true)
  {
     @Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Edit User", "btn btn-warning btn-sm", new { UserName = item.UserName })
  }
```

MenuOfRole brings back every permission for the RoleUser signed in. Depending on the Controller and Action I am able to extract what i need for where i am at.

Any ideas as to why it is not working in the View. And also if there is a cleaner and easier way to do this - I'm all ears!

Thanks

UPDATE:
I did a check in the view - just returning the ViewBag and it is coming back true, but in the Controller it is saying it is false. I am not sure why that is. If ViewBag is set in the Controller as false It should show in the view as false, should it not?

Edit: By Request here is my ForEach loop.

```
<tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LockoutEndDateUtc)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td>

          @if (ViewBag.Edit == true)
          {
             @Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Edit User", "btn btn-warning btn-sm", new { UserName = item.UserName })
          }
          @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
          {
             @Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("PW Reset", "SendResetPassword", "Account", "Reset Password", "btn btn-info btn-sm", new { UserName = item.UserName })
             <text>&nbsp;</text>
             @Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Conf E-Mail", "SendEmailConfirm", "Account", "Email Confirmation", "btn btn-info btn-sm", new { UserName = item.UserName })
          }
          @if ((item.UserName.ToLower() != this.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()))
          {
            if (ViewBag.Delete == true)
            {
               @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", null, new { UserName = item.UserName },
               new { onclick = "return Confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');", @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" })
             }
             <div class="btn-group">
                 @Html.ActionLinkAuthorized("Edit Roles", "Edit", "Roles", new { UserName = item.UserName }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-sm" }, true)
             </div>
         }
        </td>
     </tr>
    }
 </tbody>
```

Update: For a complete answer to this go to this post.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/60173428/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173428/getting-aspnet-users-roleid-for-comparison-in-permissions)

Comment: `If ViewBag is set in the Controller as false It should show in the view as false, should it not?` --- perhaps you are checking ViewBag before assignment or in different controller action/view because you are setting ViewBag values only if action name is in certain list?

Comment: Yes the ViewBag in the controller is in BaseController and this would be UsersController But UsersController : BaseController. For now it seems to be working. I still have testing to do Before i can say it is 100%. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the following line returns collection of booleans :

```
menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsUpdate));
```

so, ViewBag.Edit (same explanation for others which are assigned to ViewBag)

That is the reason why `@if (ViewBag.Edit = true)` is not evaluated correctly.

To fix this, modify the section of code to use FirstOrDefault() to return just one element from collection in controller as follows:

```
if (GetOrPost == "GET")
 {
    if (actionName == "add" || actionName == "index" || actionName == "create" || actionName == "edit" || actionName == "delete" || actionName == "multiviewindex")
    {
      ViewBag.Add = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsAdd)).FirstOrDefault();
      ViewBag.Read = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsRead)).FirstOrDefault();
      ViewBag.Create = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsCreate)).FirstOrDefault();
      ViewBag.Edit = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsUpdate)).FirstOrDefault();
      ViewBag.Delete = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsDelete)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
  }
```

Please note, I recommended using FirstOrDefault() on the assumption that collection will contain same value/s. What I meant by same value/s is collection contain either all true or all false but not mix of true and false.

If your collection contains both true and false then you need to use `Any` as follows:

```
if (GetOrPost == "GET")
{
    if (actionName == "add" || actionName == "index" || actionName == "create" || actionName == "edit" || actionName == "delete" || actionName == "multiviewindex")
    {
      ViewBag.Add = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsAdd);
      ViewBag.Read = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsRead);
      ViewBag.Create = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsCreate);
      // Any will be evaluated to true if any of item's MenuURL is equal to controllerName and IsUpdate set to true. false will be returned otherwise. Same explanation for others as well.
      ViewBag.Edit = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsUpdate);
      ViewBag.Delete = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by same values? any of these could be true or false according to what the role has access too.

Comment: Adding the FirstOrDefault did not seem to help. View is still showing button when bool is false..

Comment: You are saying that collection might contain both true and false values. So, it might be possible that First value in the collection is false. I will update the answer to use `Any`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please verify it when you get a chance.

Comment: I was playing around with this. I have not implemented your last change yet. However it appears that it was having an issue because it was in a ForEach. I put a Var Edit = ViewBag.Edit outside the foreach and then called the If(Edit == true){ } And it appears to work. Just so you know this isnt dependant on IsUpdate. They will all be set in the database as to what permission they have. Could be all false or just one false. However if All is false, they would not have access to the page anyway..

Comment: I will circle back around to this. I have to do some more testing to make sure all is working. I did change it to your latest edit. I want to make sure that all the view are working accordingly.

Comment: @Scott Purtan  hank you.. If you paste your complete code with for loop, then we can help you with complete query.

Comment: I will post it in a few. The weird thing is now that it has changed from the original I am now using if (ViewBag == true) where before it would not let me use the double equals. But it seems to be working now in the ForEach. I will post it for clarity.