# Getting AspNet Users RoleId for Comparison In permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a area where the RoleId is kept as a string in the permissions table. I am doing a comparison on the Id to pull all permissions for the Role. I am getting the current Logged in user RoleId like this.

```
 var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
 string roleid = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
```

It does not like the usage of string. I am getting

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'
```

Here is where i am doing the comparison, Note the permission can have either UserId or RoleId, I do not have a problem for the UserId with this setup.

```
var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl && String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.RoleId = roleid) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.UserId = userid));
```

Is there a different way to get the RoleId or maybe different verbiage to do the compare?

Thanks

Update: Added Controller below. Sorry it is long..

```
   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        try
        {
            //int roleid = int.Parse(Env.GetUserInfo("roleid"));
            //int userid = int.Parse(Env.GetUserInfo("userid"));
            string userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            //string userid = Env.GetUserInfo("userid");
            //string roleid = Env.GetUserInfo("roleid");
            var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            // Select will return collection as opposed to scalar/single value. Pay attention to datatype here. 
            IEnumerable<string> currentUserRoles = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
            //string roleid = roles;
            var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;
            var actionName = descriptor.ActionName.ToLower();
            var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower();
            var controller = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

            var GetOrPost = context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToString();
            var checkAreaName = context.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
            string AreaName = "";
            if (checkAreaName != null)
            {
                AreaName = checkAreaName.ToString().ToLower() + "/";
            }

            var cacheItemKey = "AllMenuBar";

            var global = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheItemKey);

            if (GetOrPost == "POST")
            {
                // Added index to string 02/03/2020
                // Added add to actonName settings 02/08/2020
                ///if menupermission create,edit,delete then update value "true" in IsMenuChange file
                if (controllerName == "menupermission" && (actionName == "add" || actionName == "index" || actionName == "create" || actionName == "edit" || actionName == "delete" || actionName == "multiviewindex"))
                {
                    global = MenuBarCache(cacheItemKey, global, "shortcache");
                }
            }

            if (global == null)//if cashe is null
            {
                global = MenuBarCache(cacheItemKey, global, "60mincache");//make cache from db
            }


            var menuaccess = (MenuOfRole[])global;

            if (GetOrPost == "GET")
            {
                if (actionName == "add" || actionName == "index" || actionName == "create" || actionName == "edit" || actionName == "delete" || actionName == "multiviewindex")
                {
                    // Old Impementation May be removed at Cleanup if not used - 02/10/2020
                    //ViewBag.Add = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsAdd));
                    //ViewBag.Read = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsRead));
                    //ViewBag.Create = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsCreate));
                    //ViewBag.Edit = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsUpdate));
                    //ViewBag.Delete = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsDelete))();

                    // Stack Overflow corrections - 02/10/2020
                    ViewBag.Add = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsAdd);
                    ViewBag.Read = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsRead);
                    ViewBag.Create = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsCreate);                        
                    ViewBag.Edit = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsUpdate);
                    ViewBag.Delete = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsDelete);
                    ViewBag.Visable = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsVisable);
                }
            }

            string menuUrl = AreaName + controllerName + "/" + actionName;

            if (IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(actionName))
            {
                menuUrl = AreaName + controllerName;
            }


            var checkUrl = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => (i.MenuURL == AreaName + controllerName + "/" + actionName) || i.MenuURL == menuUrl);
            ///checkUrl: check if menu url Exists in MenuPermission if not exists then will be run
            if (checkUrl != null)
            {
                // Changed below line to use string instead of int..  01/26/2020
                //var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl && String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.RoleId = roleid) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.UserId = userid));
                // Added change to use roles as collection.
                var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl && currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId) && i.UserId == userid);
                ///check menu  && roleid && userid
                if (checkControllerActionRoleUserId != null)
                {
                    if (IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(actionName))
                    {
                        CheckAccessOfPageAction(context, actionName, checkControllerActionRoleUserId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    if (checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsRead == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsDelete == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsCreate == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsUpdate == false)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
                        {
                            UnAuthoRedirect(context);

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    var checkControllerActionRole = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl && currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId) && i.UserId == null);
                    if (checkControllerActionRole != null)
                    {

                        if (IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(actionName))
                        {
                            CheckAccessOfPageAction(context, actionName, checkControllerActionRole);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (checkControllerActionRole.IsRead == false || checkControllerActionRole.IsDelete == false || checkControllerActionRole.IsCreate == false || checkControllerActionRole.IsUpdate == false)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
                            {
                                UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (IsThisAjaxRequest() == false)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
                        {
                            UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                        }

                    }


                }


            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
```

UPDATE: 
After implementing What @Sam suggested below I also needed to find a way to not give access to users that are not in the permissions table. To avoid redundancy. If a user does not have access to something then i shouldn't need to add it to permissions to make sure they do not have access. I added to a section of below code to redirect to the Dashboard if a user lands on a page they do not have access to.

```
var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl && currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId)
&& (i.UserId == userid || i.UserId == null) || controllerName == "dashboard"// @Sam: This is how we can combine
    );
    ///check menu  && roleid && userid
    if (checkControllerActionRoleUserId != null)
      {
        if (IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(actionName))
          {
            CheckAccessOfPageAction(context, actionName, checkControllerActionRoleUserId);
          }
          else
          {
            if (checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsRead == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsDelete == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsCreate == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsUpdate == false)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
             {
                UnAuthoRedirect(context);

             }
         }
      } 
      else
      {
        UnAuthorizedArea(context);
      }
```

Comment: A particular user can have different role/s. Is there any specific role you are looking for?

Comment: Not looking for a particular role, just the role the user is in. However you are right the user may have more than 1 role, which may propose an issue with this collection. As i would like to return everything that the user has access too. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your code is already written in such a way to return all the roles. Its just you are assigning to string. Please change `string roleid` to `IEnumerable<string> roles`. Please refer my answer below especially the code underneath FIX section. There are two other issues in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your code. After fixing the current error you will get more errors:

1. You are assigning collection of strings to string (via string roleid). Currently you are getting this error. After fixing this error below errors will come.

The reason why you are getting error is because:

- The below statement returns collection of roles (roleId collection to be precise) of logged in user as opposed to single role id.

  ```
  string roleid = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);`
  ```
- And then you are trying to **assign** this roleid collection to scalar property i.RoleId (via i.RoleId **=** roleid) in the next statement

  ```
  var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl &&  String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.RoleId = roleid) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.UserId = userid));`
  ```

  2. Using assignment operator = instead of `==` for comparison. So, you are trying to assign roleid to i.RoleId which is not allowed.
  3. Using assignment operator = instead of == for comparison. So, you are trying to assign userid to i.UserId which is not allowed.

**Fix:** Please modify your roleId section as below:

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
// Select will return collection as opposed to scalar/single value. Pay attention to datatype here. 
IEnumerable<string> currentUserRoles = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
```

(OR)

```
//You can use var in case you do not know the data types of result.
var currentUserRoles = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
```

currentUserRoles will contain all the roles of current logged in user. Now use that collection as below (please notice the condition **currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId)**. I also fixed condition around userid.):

```
var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl 
      && currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId) && i.UserId == userid);
```

Alternatively, above statement can be split using Where and FirstOrDefault as follows:

```
// Where statement returns collection of menuaccess items meeting all three conditions
var filteredMenuAccessCollection = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl && currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId) && i.UserId == userid);
// FirstOrDefault will return the first menuaccess item from filteredMenuAccessCollection
var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = filteredMenuAccessCollection.FirstOrDefault();
```

The above can **further be re-written** as follows:

```
var mathingMenuUrlMenuAccessCollection = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl); // return menuaccess items matching given menuurl
var mathingMenuUrlAndRolesMenuAccessCollection = mathingMenuUrlMenuAccessCollection.Where(i => currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId)); // return menuaccess items matching roles in currentUserRoles
var filteredMenuAccessCollection = mathingMenuUrlAndRolesMenuAccessCollection.Where(i => i.UserId == userid); // return menuaccess items matching given userid
// FirstOrDefault will return the first menuaccess item from filteredMenuAccessCollection
var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = filteredMenuAccessCollection.FirstOrDefault();
```

To summarize, All 3 condition have to be satisfied to get item from menuaccess collection otherwise null will be returning. The order of conditions evaluation is

- first it tries to find matching menuUrl items from menuaccess collection.
- Then tries to find a menuaccess item where RoleId is contained in currentUserRoles  collection.
- Then it tries to find matching userid items from menuaccess collection.

If there are multiple menuaccess items meeting the above 3 conditions then it will return the First item from the menuaccess colletion since we are using FirstOrDefault.

**Update**: Simplified version of OnActionExecuting:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    try
    {
        //int roleid = int.Parse(Env.GetUserInfo("roleid"));
        //int userid = int.Parse(Env.GetUserInfo("userid"));
        string userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        //string userid = Env.GetUserInfo("userid");
        //string roleid = Env.GetUserInfo("roleid");
        var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        // Select will return collection as opposed to scalar/single value. Pay attention to datatype here. 
        IEnumerable<string> currentUserRoles = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
        //string roleid = roles;
        // @Sam: Added this variable
        var actionNamesToCompare = new List<string>{"add", "index", "create", "edit", "delete", "multiviewindex"};
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;
        var actionName = descriptor.ActionName.ToLower();
        var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower();
        var controller = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

        var GetOrPost = context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToString();
        var checkAreaName = context.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
        string AreaName = "";
        if (checkAreaName != null)
        {
            AreaName = checkAreaName.ToString().ToLower() + "/";
        }

        var cacheItemKey = "AllMenuBar";

        var global = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheItemKey);

        if (GetOrPost == "POST")
        {
            // Added index to string 02/03/2020
            // Added add to actonName settings 02/08/2020
            ///if menupermission create,edit,delete then update value "true" in IsMenuChange file
            if (controllerName == "menupermission" && actionNamesToCompare.Contains(actionName))
            {
                global = MenuBarCache(cacheItemKey, global, "shortcache");
            }
        }

        if (global == null)//if cashe is null
        {
            global = MenuBarCache(cacheItemKey, global, "60mincache");//make cache from db
        }


        var menuaccess = (MenuOfRole[])global;

        if (GetOrPost == "GET")
        {
            if (actionNamesToCompare.Contains(actionName))
            {
                // Old Impementation May be removed at Cleanup if not used - 02/10/2020
                //ViewBag.Add = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsAdd));
                //ViewBag.Read = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsRead));
                //ViewBag.Create = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsCreate));
                //ViewBag.Edit = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsUpdate));
                //ViewBag.Delete = menuaccess.Where(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName).Select(i => (i.IsDelete))();

                // Stack Overflow corrections - 02/10/2020
                ViewBag.Add = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsAdd);
                ViewBag.Read = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsRead);
                ViewBag.Create = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsCreate);                        
                ViewBag.Edit = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsUpdate);
                ViewBag.Delete = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsDelete);
                ViewBag.Visable = menuaccess.Any(i => i.MenuURL == controllerName && i.IsVisable);
            }
        }

        // @sam: you can combine menuUrl evaluation like this using ternary operator.
        var menuUrl = IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(actionName) ? AreaName + controllerName
                      : AreaName + controllerName + "/" + actionName;

        // var checkUrl = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => (i.MenuURL == AreaName + controllerName + "/" + actionName) || i.MenuURL == menuUrl);

        // @sam: No need of this if statement
        // var checkUrl = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => (i.MenuURL == AreaName + controllerName + "/" + actionName) || i.MenuURL == menuUrl);
        ///checkUrl: check if menu url Exists in MenuPermission if not exists then will be run
        /*if (checkUrl != null)
        {
            // Changed below line to use string instead of int..  01/26/2020
            //var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl && String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.RoleId = roleid) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.UserId = userid));
            // Added change to use roles as collection.
            // @Sam: Since both if and else are doing same of operations, 
            //       the below if-else can be comibined as follows:

            /*var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl  &&currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId) && i.UserId == userid);
            ///check menu  && roleid && userid
            if (checkControllerActionRoleUserId != null)
            {
                if (IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(actionName))
                {
                    CheckAccessOfPageAction(context, actionName, checkControllerActionRoleUserId);
                }
                else
                {
                if (checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsRead == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsDelete == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsCreate == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsUpdate == false)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
                    {
                        UnAuthoRedirect(context);

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var checkControllerActionRole = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl && currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId) && i.UserId == null);
                if (checkControllerActionRole != null)
                {

                    if (IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(actionName))
                    {
                        CheckAccessOfPageAction(context, actionName, checkControllerActionRole);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (checkControllerActionRole.IsRead == false || checkControllerActionRole.IsDelete == false || checkControllerActionRole.IsCreate == false || checkControllerActionRole.IsUpdate == false)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
                        {
                            UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (IsThisAjaxRequest() == false)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
                    {
                        UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                    }

                }
            }//
        } */
        var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MenuURL == menuUrl  &&currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId) 
         && (i.UserId == userid || i.UserId == null) // @Sam: This is how we can combine
         );
        ///check menu  && roleid && userid
        if (checkControllerActionRoleUserId != null)
        {
            if (IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(actionName))
            {
                CheckAccessOfPageAction(context, actionName, checkControllerActionRoleUserId);
            }
            else
            {
            if (checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsRead == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsDelete == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsCreate == false || checkControllerActionRoleUserId.IsUpdate == false)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
                {
                    UnAuthoRedirect(context);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```

You can test with your data for different users.

Comment: So in this code it will only return if it matches - hence the Contains? Or will it get all that match. This isn't a loop. So if it returns more that 1 role for the user, will it find all the permissions for the user?

Comment: If you want to return **everything** (meaning every meanuaccess item) that current Logged In User has access to then you will need to use **Where**. If you want any **single menuaccess** item that the user can access, then you will need to use **FirstOrDefault**

Comment: I am going to add the controller Protected overide void to the top. Just want you to see what is going on in the whole thing. That way there is no grey areas. In summary i would like to return all permissions for the user if they are just in permissions in some items with userId and part of a role as well. So would have to check all and give access to all.

Comment: So I put in the code above without the FirstOrDefault. I am now getting an error on checkControllerActionRoleUserId in the "If" Statement that say Cannot convert 'System.Collections.IEnumerable<MyProject.Controllers.BaseController.MenuOfRole>' to 'MyProject.Controllers.BaseController.MenuOfRole'

Comment: Also not understanding using the Where instead of FirstOrDefault.. Do I  omit this line?  var checkControllerActionRoleUserId = filteredMenuAccessCollection.FirstOrDefault(); and replace FilteredMenuaccessCollection with checkControlleractionRoleUserId? This is where i get the error i mentioned is last message.

Comment: @ScottPurtan you can just use checkControlleractionRoleUserId. I just showed you how things work behind the scenes so its easy for you to follow the flow. Also, I simplified your OnActionExecuting function, you can try testing that if you want. In the function I have added my comments starting with `// @Sam` .

Comment: @ScottPurtan Linq Where returns collection after applying the criteria specified in Where clause(you can think of it as SELECT * from tbl where <some_conditions> ... in SQL query language). Linq Select is to project the required properties (you can think of it as SELECT id, name ... in SQL query language.. here you are projecting id, name). FirstOrDefault is to retrieve single item from the collection.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. This code was written by someone else and if something i have not gotten into. I have implemented the new OnActionExecuting and seem to be working. I have not tried it with other users yet. I am re-doing my business site, this is something i added to it. Now i have to finish the rest. I will test with my test accounts as soon as i get a couple other things done. FYI.. I wouldn't be doing this if the people i hired would have done it right the first. Again thank you!

Comment: One more bit to the puzzle.. Right now this is dependent on the fact that there is a permission set it the MenuPermissions table. Meaning if it is not put in the table that they do not have permission to the items it will automatically give access. MenuItem will  not show up but a logged in person could navigate to the page and have access. Is there a way to wrap this in an if statement so that if the Role or user for that controller is null it will just redirect them to the home dashboard page. I will try a few things. but would like to hear your input on it. thanks.